# Is possible to have a custom SQLite build for Core Data?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

SQLite reportedly became much faster compared to older versions, performance gain is said to be 50%! (source: [50% faster than 3.7.17](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.sqlite.general/90549)).

For Core Data, Apple uses 3.7.13 from June 2012, so I am wondering if it is possible to bundle a custom build of SQLite and tell Core Data to use it?

I know that is possible for jailbroken devices, but I'm looking for a solution for App Store apps.

Comment: So most of your app's CPU time is inside the database? Did you measure this?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 percent certain of all the details but it looks like that as long as you can statically compile and link the latest version of SQLite, that you could then use `NSIncrementalStore` as a bridge between your SQL backend and Core Data.

This is the best introduction to `NSIncrementalStore` I have found http://nshipster.com/nsincrementalstore/